# How safe is it to increase tmpfs to more than physical memory?

Tags: linux, swap, tmpfs

My server has 2GB RAM and 120GB SSD, plus some RAID arrays for storage. OS is Debian 8 (Linux 3.16).

I have a MySQL intense application that has `tmpdir` = `/run/mysqld`, which is a `tmpfs` configured by Debian through `/etc/default/tmpfs`:

```
# Size limits.  Please see tmpfs(5) for details on how to configure
# tmpfs size limits.
TMPFS_SIZE=40%VM
```

This used to be `20%VM`, which is about 384M. I ran against several `no space left on device`, so I've increased it to `40%VM`, but even with about 763M it is still too small.

Now I now I should add more RAM, but out of curiosity, I'd like to know the limits here.

- `/dev/sdd1` is mounted on `/` has about 50GB free, and is fairly fast (Samsung 850 EVO SSD)
- `/dev/sdd5` is my swap partition, it is 3.7G (fdisk type ID is 82)
- `TMPFS_SIZE` is set to `40%VM`, meaning `/run` is 763M

Now I know that tmpfs can swap, which is fine with me. I want MySQL to write to RAM whenever possible, but if it needs more memory, I can allow the system to swap it on the SSD.

So with my setup, can I push `/run` to be:

- 300M big? Yes. That was the default.
- 1.5GB big? Yes, tried, MySQL used up to 1.3GB on it and the system worked like a charm. But that's still less than half physical memory + swap partition.
- 2.5GB big? This is more than physical memory, but less than half the physical memory + my swap partition.
- 4GB big? This would tightly fit in half physical + swap
- More? like 10GB? can it use free space on `/` to swap more?

I'm guessing the rule of thumb for safety is to have `TMPFS_SIZE` not larger than swap + half physical memory. Can I go beyond this without increasing the swap partition?

Also, is it possible to put `200%VM` in `/etc/default/tmpfs`? I've read [`tmpfs(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html) without knowing if I can put >100% on this.

Last, should I do it in `/etc/fstab` instead and don't touch `/etc/default/tmpfs`?

(up to know I've only done it with `mount -o remount`, I did not reboot the server yet)

Edit: for the last question, I know it can/may be modified by `/etc/fstab` (see quote below from man page), however I wanted to know the best practice, because I've never touched anything in `/etc/default` so far.

> More complex mount options may be used by the creation of a suitable entry in /etc/fstab.

Comment: Interesting question. I guess this might also be very much related to the memory overcommit setting.

Comment: It seems that the maximum tmpfs size would be physical+swap. I've seen this [in the kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt).

Answer (score 9):

I figured I could just test it, so I ran:

```
sudo mount -o remount,size=2800M /run
```

Worked like a charm:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           2.8G   45M  2.7G   2% /run
```

So I filled it a bit:

```
fallocate -l 1G /run/test.img
fallocate -l 1G /run/test2.img
fallocate -l 500M /run/test3.img
```

Result:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           2.8G  2.6G  208M  93% /run
```

System is still up and running. Swap availability dropped, which proves it was used:

[image: swap availability drop]

- 17:10: create 2.5 GB of files in `/run`
- 17:20: remove the 500M file

Total swap is reduced by the amount taken by `/run`.

I'd test 10GB on a VM, because I don't know if the kernel will refuse the remount or just have an unexpected behavior.

I'm still looking for an actual answer, but the pragmatic way showed it works.